# Can you wrap or alter the size of the text on an azure monior chart

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

We use azure monitor for our internal monitoring, and we have quite long descriptions for some charts. I love to wrap or reduce the size of this text, so the chart looks better

```
customMetrics
|extend Dec_Reasion = tostring(customDimensions["DeclineReason"])
|extend Type = tostring(customDimensions["AcquiringInstitutionId"])
|where name =='TransactionsDeclined'
|summarize sum(valueCount) by tostring(Dec_Reasion), bin(timestamp, 1h)
```

[image]

the bar chart is even worse!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of now, currently there is no option to modify the size of the text in a KQL result set. You can use alternate workaround to achieve this

#### Using Dashboard

In your Azure Monitor Query Editor after query result. You can pin the result into dashboard. In Dashboard we have a flexibility to increase the overall result.
[image]

View in Dashboard
[image]

If it really requires for future purpose reopen a feature request in [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/chart-size-in-queries-should-be-customisable-to-in/751633).